# How to change/set value in kendo combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, kendo-ui

Can anyone let me know how can we change the value of kendo combobox dynamically.

Fiddle is here - http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/yL6w3/1/

In the above fiddle, when we click on `click` then the shown value should be changed to `three` (for eg.)

I found this link which list all datasource methods - 
http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/framework/datasource/methods.aspx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Bxsge/2/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/Bxsge/1/ (behavior for demo when you will click on the link the select will change to `three` selected value.)

selects by jQuery object `// selects by index combobox.select(1); // selects item`

link: http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/ui-widgets/combobox/methods.aspx

Hope this helps, `:)`

**code**

```
$(function(){
    var CB = $("select").kendoComboBox();
  
    $("a").click(function(){
        
         var $cbx = $("select").data("kendoComboBox")
         
         $cbx.select(2);
       
    });
});
​
```

Comment: How about kendodropdownlist. It doesn't work the way it mentioned.

Comment: The `select(n)` method selects an item by its index, _n_, an integer. The `value(v)` method selects an item by its item's value, _v_, a string. The `text(t)` method changes the textbox content and will select an item if it finds one with matching text, _t_, a string.

Comment: Well what if we don't know the index value. If it is dynamic value then how would we set value and text

Answer (score 26):

If you know the value you want, you can also do:

```
$("#MyComboBox").data("kendoComboBox").value(id);
```

Comment: What if i want to set the default value to be selected (---selecte option---), the -1 index, you know what i mean?

Comment: ohh i got it $("#MyComboBox").data("kendoComboBox").value(-1);